# Getting garbage value while passing an entire array to a function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to pass an entire array to the function but the last value i get is always a garbage value and not 3. Please point out where I've made a mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main() {
    int array[3] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    display(&array[0], 3);
}
display(int *j, int n) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        printf("\n%d", *j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass "an entire array to a function" -- C does not do this. Instead, you are passing a *pointer* to the first element of the array.

```
main() {
    int array[3] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

`main` should be declared `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. It's not that horrible to type, and you can even get your text editor to do it for you, if you care enough.

You have declared `array` to contain only three items, but store *four* items into the array. This should have thrown a compile warning at the least. Pay attention to those warnings. Don't specify the size of your array unless that size is *vital* (Say, if you wanted to keep track of US states, then `int states[50] = { ... };` might make sense. For now. Maybe this is a bad example.)

```
for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    printf("\n%d", *j);
    j++;
```

`for(i=0; i<=n; i++)` is very often a bug -- C array indexes run from `0` to `n-1`, not `0` to `n`. You're reading one-past-the-array, and that value is not surprisingly garbage.

Further this code is awkward; you should just use `printf("\n%d", j[i])` and *not* increment `j` each time. Incrementing *two* variables as "loop variables" this way is a recipe for writing bugs in the future. (If you need to update two variables with every loop iteration, place *both* in the last section of the `for(;;i++, j++)` loop.)

Answer (score 3):

You have an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in your for loop. Your array has only three elements. You try to read *four* elements instead of three.

Change your code to this (note the `<` instead of `<=`):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

You also try to initialize the array with four elements when it only has room for three:

```
int array[3] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Maybe you can try to change your compiler settings to flag this as a warning/error. Then you might get something like this that would notify you of the problem:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:13: error: excess elements in array initializer
prog.c:13: error: (near initialization for ‘array’)
```

Comment: the off by one error doesn't matter given the way he's used calling display

Comment: @sashang: wrong -- once you've dereferenced an array outside of bounds, you've brought the wrath of [undefined behavior](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) onto your program.

Comment: @sarnold: if he'd declared the array with 4 elements instead of three then the way display was called, display(...,3) would index into the array correctly.

Comment: @sashang: If the array had been declared with 4 elements, he would presumably also change it to `display(&array[0], 4);`. Then it again would fail.

Comment: @MarkByers: I'm just trying to explain why I made the original comment so bear with me. The comment was made when your original answer only mentioned the off by one error and you posted a correction the loop. Given the code originally posted, this alone would not have answered the question (in other words he would have seen the sequence 0,1,2 and not 3 as he wanted), hence my comment. Subsequently you identified the real issue and ammended your post with the part about array needing to be sized to 4 elements.

Answer (score 3):

The array variable represent an address of first element so no need to use `&` address operator with the function call and another issue is with `size` of an array.

```
main() {
    int array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    display(array, 3);
}
display(int *j, int n) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        printf("\n%d", *j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There a few observations in the code:
1. `main()` should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Also you need to return an int value from `main` when to change it to `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`
2. You are initializing an array of 3 elements with 4 values.
Either declare as `int array[3] = {0, 1, 2};` or as `int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};` (this will create an array with 4 elements)
3. `display(int *j, int n)` should have a return type say `void display(int *j, int n)`  (otherwise it default to `int` in which case the function is not returning any value). In this case you will have to define the function before using.
4. In current case, to the function `display` you are passing an array of 3 elements and accessing element at index 3 (when `i` equals `n`) in the `for` loop which is the 4th element (i.e. out of bounds which is undefined behavior). Remember that array in C is zero indexed. So `for(i=0; i<=n; i++)` should be `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your array is declared to have 3 elements yet you initialize it with 4:

```
int array[3] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Answer (score 1):

You create an array for only 3 integers, but put 4 in it. But the error is when you print the array, you print four entries, though only three exist.